# Simple html page renders differently in Firefox and IE. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

Below is the code of a Form that I am creating. The CSS code that it links to, has also been added after this code. The problem is that it renders differently in Firefox and IE. How to stabilize it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Add/Update Political Party</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Lib/entryformstyle.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sectionEntryForm" class="entryForm" style="width:300px">
    <table id="tblEntryForm" cols="2" class="entryFormTable" border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="white">
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Add / Update Political Party</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Party full name:</td>
            <td><input id="inPartyFullName" name="inPartyFullName" accept="text/plain" maxlength="80" class="inputBoxStyle" size="40"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Party short name (initials):</td>
            <td><input id="inPartyShortName" name="inPartyShortName" accept="text/plain" maxlength="10" class="inputBoxStyle"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total members in party:</td>
            <td><input id="inTotalMembers" name="inTotalMembers" accept="text/plain" maxlength="6" class="inputBoxStyle"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Chairman:</td>
            <td><input id="inChairman" name="inChairman" accept="text/plain" maxlength="80" class="inputBoxStyle"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vice-chairman:</td>
            <td><input id="inViceChairman" name="inViceChairman" accept="text/plain" maxlength="80" class="inputBoxStyle"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Founder:</td>
            <td><input id="inFounder" name="inFounder" accept="text/plain" maxlength="80" class="inputBoxStyle"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date formed (dd/MM/yyyy):</td>
            <td><input id="inDateFormed" name="inDateFormed" accept="text/plain" maxlength="10" class="inputBoxStyle"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input id="btnMenu" name="btnMenu" type="button" value="Return to Menu"></td>
            <td align="center"><input id="btnClear" name="btnClear" type="button" value="Clear Entries"></td>
            <td align="center"><input id="btnUpdate" name="btnUpdate" type="button" value="Update Record"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
div.entryForm
{
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: black;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

div.entryFormTable
{
    border:thin;
    border-color:black;
}

input.entryFormColor
{

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference?

Comment: And why exactly do you have a style attribute in the div tag when you also have a rule in your stylesheet? ;)

Comment: can you tell which is correct one is it IE or Firefox?

Comment: Which versions of IE and FF?  IE6 (and 7, 8 in Quirks mode) suffer from the box model problem, so padding and margin used together will produce different result.  IE8 in Standards mode has fixed this.

Comment: @Franz: I just wanted to use "width" in-line. I don't want to include it in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone suggested me to set the background color of the table as well. Setting the background color of the table as that of the DIV, solved the problem.

Thanks all for suggesting various alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

[Do websites need to look exactly the same in every browser?](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)

Hint: No.

Comment: @keir: At least the entry forms.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @gevorg Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot: Try defining specific widths on your table cells so that IE and FF hold the table cells open at the same sizes.  Make sure they add up to 300px.

Comment: For each table cell add a width property that is appropriate for that column:  <td width="100">.  Like I said, this is a long shot since you didn't really say what is the problem between IE and FF.  I am just assuming it is going to be that the table cell widths are not matching.

Comment: @Jeff: The problem is that the entry form displayed by FF has half of the form with background lightgrey, while IE displays entire form with lightgrey.

Comment: Try putting a <div style="clear:both;"></div> after the closing </table> tag but before the closing </div> tag.